# Cayley graph of a finitely generated group $G$

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

Good time of day!

I'm trying to show that: "The Cayley graph of a finitely generated group $G$ is quasi-isometric to a line if and only if $G$ has a cyclic subgroup of finite index".

My thoughts about this: I was trying to apply Svarc-Milnor lemma which states

" Let G be a group acting by isometries on a proper length space $X$ such that the action is properly discontinuous and cocompact. Then the group $G$ is finitely generated and for every finite generating set $S$ of $G$ and every point $p\in X$ the orbit map

$f_{p}:(G,d_{S}) \to X$, $g \to gp$ is a quasi-isometry. Here ${\displaystyle d_{S}}$ is the word metric on $G$ corresponding to $S$.

I'm not sure about this attempt. Please can you explain this in more details?
Thank you!

Comment: I take it you mean “*infinite* cyclic subgroup of finite index”, otherwise $G$ can be finite.

Comment: With this type of an argument, you can prove that each virtually ${\mathbb Z}$-group is quasi-isometric to the real line. The converse direction is harder. The result itself follows from the fact that a 2-ended group is virtually cyclic.